# CSS inheriting oddities

Tags: css, css-selectors

I run into this a lot and it's fairly annoying. Does anyone know about this:

```
#content h5 {
color:red;
}

#next h5 {
color:blue;
}
```

When the markup looks like this:

```
<div id="content>
  <h5>RED</h5>

  <div id="next">
    <h5>BLUE</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

The blue h5 will actually appear red, what gives?!

Comment: There is a typo in your markup, id="content" needs a closing quote (assuming this is just a typo in the example). The concept is working okay for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE 8 at http://jsfiddle.net/AWVdY/
What browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I had no problems with it. You do have a quote mark missing after content though. Below is what I tested with

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content h5 {
color:red;
}

#next h5 {
color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <h5>RED</h5>

  <div id="next">
    <h5>BLUE</h5>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[No, it won't](http://jsbin.com/icuqi3).

Answer (score 0):

That's because of what is known as **CSS Specificity**, here is a good tutorial about it:

[Specifics On CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)